# Which statistical software can do Weibull analysis and draw these particular figures?

Tags: weibull-distribution

Some R packages, Weibull++, and a couple of other programs can perform Weibull analysis (survival analysis by fitting a Weibull distribution). But I need the one that can both do Weibull regression and draw the attached figures (not similar figures, but exactly these figures). I am interested in the particular program that can draw these images, not for example the MASS package of R which can give similar Weibull cdfs.

[image: Which software can draw such boxplots?]

Simple box plots. This is only added in order to facilitate the identification of the used stats program. Not many stats programs use such layouts for plots. So this might help finding the program used to create the below image.

[image: Which software can draw such Weibull cumulative distributions?]

Weibull cumulative distributions.

Comment: The term 'Weibull analysis' is a little ambiguous. Do you want to estimate lifetime distributions in the presence of censoring by fitting Weibull-type regression models?

Comment: Are you basically asking for software that can draw overlaid line plots on common axes?  (That is what it seems like.)

Comment: Glen, yes I want to do survival analysis using Weibull regression as an alternative to the Cox regression.

Comment: Whuber, no I am curious to know the particular software that has created these very images. There are numerous programs that can draw similar plots. However, I am interested in the visuals of these images, and am seeking the program that has created *these* plots, not programs that can create similar plots in other formats (eg, using other fonts, axis styles, plot properties, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I presume the first plot is simply a plot of observed lifetimes and the second plot is a fitted Weibull cdf. (You should explicitly define what it is you're drawing.)

R can certainly draw both those figures. Quite easily in fact; it would only require a couple of lines of R commands in each case.

Are these 2-parameter Weibulls you're drawing? What are you parameter estimates?

Here's an example of two Weibull cdfs on the one plot; you can do six as easily as two. The few cosmetic differences (labels, the gap between the border and the axes, the specific form of dashed lines and so on, orientation of tick mark labels, even the fonts and font sizes) are all relatively simple to change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the figure you drew using R is similar to the one I posted. I am interested to draw such figures and have researched the relevant R packages (MASS and Weibulltoolkit). However, in this question of mine, I want to explore and identify the very program that has created exactly these plots. 
On a side note, my parameter estimates are the magnitude of force.

Comment: Ah, sorry, your question wasn't especially clear, then. I had thought you were looking for any program that *could* do such plots. You should replace "can also draw" with "drew". [Of course any package that could exactly reproduce them *might actually have made them*.] Can you give more clues -- how/where did you encounter them?

Comment: Glen thanks for the additions to your comment. Sure I will edit my post.
I saw those figures in an article (which prefer not to mention in public). They had not stated the program used for statistical analysis, so I wonder how did they do it so nicely (I pretty liked the visuals of these plots but hadn't seen them before). I suspect they are drawn using either SAS or STATA. SAS friends confirmed SAS default generic plots are not like this. So remains Stata. SPSS and other packages I know can't draw these.

Comment: Stata (not STATA) won't support those horrible patterns in box plots, nor by default will it support axis ticks that are both inward and outward facing.